# "value at is not a member of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode" error

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm getting this error message when trying to compile code migrated from one Scala project to another. What can be the reason?

UPD sample: `item.at("/name").asText()` (where item is a Json node)

Comment: We will need a sample of the code triggering the error to answer your question.

Comment: @Moebius, here you are.

Comment: It probably means "value at is not a member of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode”! In other words, you're calling a method that doesn't exist. Without a better example of the code (and libraries) you're using, it's pretty much impossible for us to tell why you're getting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no at function associated with the JsonNode class :
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Maybe the version of jackson library is different between the two project and the at function is now deprecated.